# Error installing apache-airflow. Fails at installing pendulum

Tags: python, pip, airflow, python-poetry, pendulum

I am trying to install apache-airflow in vscode (windows OS). I have the following versions installed.
Python 3.11.1
pip 23.0.1

I am trying to install with the following command

```
 pip --proxy 'proxy address' install apache-airflow
```

I get the following error while trying to install

```
Collecting apache-airflow
  Using cached apache_airflow-2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (11.8 MB)
Collecting alembic<2.0,>=1.6.3
  Using cached alembic-1.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (210 kB)
Collecting argcomplete>=1.10
  Using cached argcomplete-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting attrs>=22.1.0
  Using cached attrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting blinker
  Using cached blinker-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting cattrs>=22.1.0
  Using cached cattrs-22.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting colorlog<5.0,>=4.0.2
  Using cached colorlog-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting configupdater>=3.1.1
  Using cached ConfigUpdater-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting connexion[flask]>=2.10.0
  Using cached connexion-2.14.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting cron-descriptor>=1.2.24
  Using cached cron_descriptor-1.2.35.tar.gz (29 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting croniter>=0.3.17
  Using cached croniter-1.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=0.9.3 in c:\users\username\desktop\airflow_tutorial\airflow_env\lib\site-packages (from apache-airflow) (39.0.1)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2.13
  Using cached Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting dill>=0.2.2
  Using cached dill-0.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (110 kB)
Collecting flask<2.3,>=2.2
  Using cached Flask-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting flask-appbuilder==4.1.4
  Using cached Flask_AppBuilder-4.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting flask-caching>=1.5.0
  Using cached Flask_Caching-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting flask-login>=0.6.2
  Using cached Flask_Login-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting flask-session>=0.4.0
  Using cached Flask_Session-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
Collecting flask-wtf>=0.15
  Using cached Flask_WTF-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting graphviz>=0.12
  Using cached graphviz-0.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting gunicorn>=20.1.0
  Using cached gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting httpx
  Using cached httpx-0.23.3-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Using cached itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting jinja2>=3.0.0
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-4.17.3-py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy
  Using cached lazy_object_proxy-1.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (22 kB)
Collecting linkify-it-py>=2.0.0
  Using cached linkify_it_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting lockfile>=0.12.2
  Using cached lockfile-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting markdown>=3.0
  Using cached Markdown-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
Collecting markdown-it-py>=2.1.0
  Using cached markdown_it_py-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting markupsafe>=1.1.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (16 kB)
Collecting marshmallow-oneofschema>=2.0.1
  Using cached marshmallow_oneofschema-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting mdit-py-plugins>=0.3.0
  Using cached mdit_py_plugins-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting packaging>=14.0
  Using cached packaging-23.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting pathspec~=0.9.0
  Using cached pathspec-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting pendulum>=2.0
  Using cached pendulum-2.1.2.tar.gz (81 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002118C9114D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/poetry-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002118C912210>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/poetry-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002118C912ED0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/poetry-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002118C913A50>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/poetry-core/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002118C      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement poetry-core>=1.0.0a9 (from versions: 
none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for poetry-core>=1.0.0a9

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

It fails at installing pendulum. Can anyone help me with the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be because poetry doesn't pick up your proxy settings. Try to set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY, see https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3748#issuecomment-799686252